# Get list of alerts of the current user from the whole site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx-webparts, react

My scenario: i want to create a spfx web part that uses a rest API that will query all the alerts throughout the whole site collection for the current user.

I want to know which API to use and better if there already is a sample i can use. I am new to spfx and am building this web part using react

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that there is no REST API that could manage nor read alerts whatsoever. Also alerts are per site (web) so it would require to iterate through all subsites which could take really long time to load.

This functionality was introduced in [CSOM](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-january-2017/) at January 2017. So long time there was no way how to manage alerts in the cloud and I don't think that it will change in near future.

Comment: is it available in jsom? If yes any code how to implement this please?

Comment: According the Uservoice it is implemented only in CSOM. https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/16520425-csom-jsom-api-to-manage-sharepoint-list-item-ale

Comment: Is it still possible to create webpart using csom on modern team site?

Comment: No it is not. CSOM is .NET SDK and cannot be used in client-side apps.